# GItLab is not deploying laravel app to AWS ec2

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, gitlab, cd

I am trying to deploy my Laravel app to AWS ec2 instance. I m using GitLab for code management and pipeline process.

Here is my .gitlab-ci.yml file.

```
    # Node docker image on which this would be run
image: node:8.9.0

#This command is run before actual stages start running
before_script:
  - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
  - npm install

stages:
  - test
  - deploy
  - production

#Production stage
production:   
   stage: production   
   before_script: 
   #generate ssh key   
     - mkdir -p ~/.ssh     
     - echo -e "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa     
     - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa     
     - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'   
   script:     

      - bash .gitlab-deploy.sh

   environment:     
      name: production     
      url: MY_HOST_IP_ADDRESS   
   when: manual
# lint and test are two different jobs in the same stage.
# This allows us to run these two in parallel and making build faste
```

And here is my .gitlab-deploy.sh file

```
#!/bin/bash
#Get servers list
set -f
string=$DEPLOY_SERVER
array=(${string//,/ })
#Iterate servers for deploy and pull last commit
for i in "${!array[@]}"; do
  echo "Deploying information to EC2 and Gitlab"
  echo "Deploy project on server ${array[i]}"
  ssh ubuntu@${array[i]} "cd /var/www/html && git pull origin"
done
```

When I push my code it's processing fine. As you can see below image.
[image]

After a successful process when I list the directory of /var/www/html it's still empty. I am using Apache2 on Ubuntu. I want to deploy my code directly AWS EC2 instance.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you are saying that you already have EC2 instance up and running, apache installed and connection to the Internet established?

Comment: @MatusDubrava Yes.